# .Net core when download file to wwwroot refreshs the page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, hangfire

Im using hangfire jobs to download files to project's wwwroot folder. When job starts, the project refreshing the page which i am in.

I tried the downloading file to Project Content Path then i can't access the files.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it happen in Release mode without debugger attached?

Comment: What do you mean by "when job starts, the project refreshing the page which I am in"? Do you mean a web page you have open in the browser? Or in your IDE?

Comment: @mason yeap html page.

Comment: @GuruStron in debug mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VS studio enable hotreload by default.

Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.BrowserLinkMiddleware is injected if options>Projects & Solutions>ASP.NET core>CSS Hot Reload is enabled.

This feature will monitor wwwroot folder files changed, it will refresh the pages.

To dsiable this feature, you could modify your VS launch settings to add below:

```
"hotReloadEnabled" : false
```

Then it will not refresh the page.